# handle clicks to UIPickerView rows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I handle clicks to UIPickerView rows with a regular method

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

but it works only for non-current rows. My problem is that I need to get taps on the already selected (current) row also. Any ideas or workarounds for didSelectRow? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put a clear button over each row and handle touches from it like any other button.

Comment: Thanks for an idea, works fine! I just fixated on UIPickerView params and methods.

Comment: No problem. I know I get caught up in one way of thinking too. Helps to have another perspective sometimes, doesn't it?

Comment: What if the rows are dynamically generated from an array of strings?

Comment: That would be the same in this case. The clear button is just over the UIPickerView to trigger an action method. You could always change the method operations depending on the data in your array, if necessary.